# Logarithmic differentiation of expressions of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives

This is a question from the book "Differential Calculus" by Joseph Edwards.

[image]

I don't understand what does it wants when it says expressions for $\sin\theta$  and $\cos\theta$ in factors. And for the rest part I don't know where to begin with.

Comment: Does the text show formulas for $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ as infinite products? Use those by applying logarithms and then differentiating.

Comment: I assume this is based off of Euler's Sine and Cosine product formulas. Since they rely on an infinite product, using the logarithm property $\ln(\prod a_n)=\sum \ln(a_n)$ will be the first step before taking the derivative.

Comment: Thank You  @Graviton @ MPW Sir.

Comment: @Graviton I am able to solve the the bit (a) using Euler's sine product formula. For the next I tried the cosine product but the result contains  in the denominator, which is not mentioned in the question (b)-(d). Please suggest a way to proceed further.

Comment: @Swayam is it possible to factor out $\pi$? I can't seem to find the product formula for the cosine function. If not, it may help to assume that $x^2=\pi^2c$. I.e; x is a multiple of $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, 'differentiate logarithmically' means, in case you have function $\varphi(\theta)$, and you need its derivative rewrite it as
$$
L \varphi(\theta) = \log (\varphi(\theta))\\
L' \varphi(\theta) = \frac{1}{\varphi(\theta)} \times \varphi'(\theta)\\
\varphi'(\theta) = L'(\varphi(\theta))\varphi(\theta)
$$
which is often easier. Try, for example, $\varphi(\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta^2}$

Comment: Sorry Sir, but I could not understand the 'L' you used here. Is it a function?

Comment: Yes it's just a name for the expression $\log \phi(x)$, e.g. for $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}, L \phi(x) = -2\log x$

Comment: Thank You Sir. I got it now.